# Inject date picker on FullCalendar's Month/Year element

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a way to inject/have a date-picker on FullCalendar's header where the Month/Year are displayed?
[Snippet of full-calendar header with highlighted portion I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T562m.png)

Thanks

Comment: Not via the API no. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/headerToolbar explains how you can control the header, it is fairly limited. You'd have to write some separate JS to append it to the relevant HTML element directly using standard DOM functions

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.